# XML File with local copy of XML Schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am trying out some XML Schema examples and have to validate them with a sample XML File. The schema is a local file (someFile.xsd). I am using eclipse and want to include a reference in the XML file to point to this local xsd file so that eclipse can suggest the elements to me.

Am finding it hard to come up with the syntax to include a local file. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the [`xsi:schemaLocation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_schemaLocation) attribute?

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://foo/target/Namespace"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:someNamespace="someFile"     
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       someFile someFile.xsd" >
...
</root>
```

I believe `someFile.xsd` has to be in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com note.xsd">
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Copied from http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_howto.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own Implementation of [ResourceResolver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSResourceResolver.html) and [LSInput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSInput.html) to the [SchemaFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html) so that the call of 
of [LSInput.getCharacterStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSInput.html#getCharacterStream) will provide a schema from a local path.

It tried to provide a [comprehensive example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996345).

The approach basically consists of a proper implementation of what is called from

```
getSchemaAsStream(input.getSystemId(), input.getBaseURI(), localPath)));
```

at the end of the following code. At this point you have to hook in with your own lookup mechanism to find schema files on your local path.

```
public void validate(InputStream xmlStream, InputStream schemaStream, String baseUri, String localPath)
                throws SAXException, IOException {
    Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(xmlStream);
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    factory.setResourceResolver((type, namespaceURI, publicId, systemId, baseURI) -> {
        LSInput input = new DOMInputImpl();
        input.setPublicId(publicId);
        input.setSystemId(systemId);
        input.setBaseURI(baseUri);
        input.setCharacterStream(new InputStreamReader(
                        getSchemaAsStream(input.getSystemId(), input.getBaseURI(), localPath)));
        return input;
    });
```